# Ruby on Rails: link_to calls custom method in controller - match method is giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to call the method "link_to" that once called - changes an attribute value of an item. So when the user calls the linked_to method for an 'item' the closed attribute for that item will change from item.close = false -> item.close = true

```
<% @items.each do |i| %>
    ...
<%= link_to "Close", item_close_path(:id => i.id) %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Within my controller method I have:

```
def close
    Item.find(params[:id]).close = true

 #redirect_to index
  end
```

Within my routes method I have:

```
match 'items/:id/close' => 'items#close', as: :items_close
```

The error I'm getting is:

> RuntimeError: You should not use the `match` method in your router
>   without specifying an HTTP method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify a HTTP method (GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, etc.). It looks like you are trying to update your Item (although it won't work, since you are not saving here). In the case of an update you want to use PATCH or PUT. I recommend to use PATCH for updates, since this is the Rails convention ([read here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/)).

You can do it like this:

```
match 'items/:id/close' => 'items#close', via: [:patch, :put], as: :items_close
```

You could also use 'patch' instead of 'match', which is cleaner if you are only using PATCH for this route:

```
patch 'items/:id/close' => 'items#close', as: :items_close
```

In the link you must also specify the HTTP method (if it's other than GET), this is how:

```
<%= link_to "Close", item_close_path(:id => i.id), method: :patch %>
```

[More info on 'match' here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match)

Comment: I'm getting an error 500 now when pressing the linked_to method.

Is it because above the match I have "resources :items" or it's because my redirect to index is not working? Is my error beyond the scope of this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the error? My guess is that the url in the link does not exists.

Comment: I just get a normal Error 500 (500). What do you mean the URL doesn't exist? Doesn't "match 'items/:id/close'" create the view "website/items/1/close"?

Comment: Have you turned on debugging? There must be a reason for the 500 error, because it isn't 'normal'.
By url I mean: `item_close_path(:id => i.id)`, is it in your routes?

Comment: I fixed it by adding get to your code: via: [:patch, :put, :get]

Comment: I forgot to mention, you must specify the HTTP method in the link to. Check the updated answer. You can remove the GET from the route if you do this.